# What is the use of returning List<?> in a method?

Tags: java, generics

e.g.

```
public interface CacheClient
{
    List<?> getKeysWithExpiryCheck();
}
```

Or should I return

```
List<Object>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) is a good intro to Java Generics. [A] and [B] explain the difference between ? and Object. Basically, ? indicates that the type is unknown which is a problem if you need to add items to the list. However, if you only read from the list it is OK to treat the result as an Object. Although, I suggest to use some thing like

```
public interface CacheClient {
    List<? extends Key> getKeysWithExpiryCheck();
}
```

[A] http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html

[B] http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Josh Bloch in Effective Java 2nd Edition recommends to return List<Key> instead List<? extends Key> because you don't loose any benefit but don't make users to use List<? extends Key> everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare your method as

```
List<Object> getKeysWithExpiryCheck();
```

You can only return `List<Object>` instances from it, and nothing else. If you e.g. try to return `List<String>`, you get a compilation error. This is because although `Object` is a supertype of `String`, `List<Object>` is not a supertype of `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be to ensure type safety? Returning a List of object means that the list could hold anything.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it means that the collection can hold any type.
However when using  it's impossible to modify the collection.

```
public void doSomething(Collection<?> col) {
    for (Object o : col) {
      System.out.println(o);
    }

    col.add("string"); //Compile Error here !
}
```

Comment: You can remove elements, and in fact add them back in.

Comment: @Tom, looks like you are correct and indeed you can remove elements from the collection.
However, the example I gave is valid and you get compilation error when trying to add object to the collection.

Comment: You gave an example of code that does not compile. That does not mean there does not exist a trick that allows you to add removed elements back in.